# How can I adapt between non zmq socket and pyzmq?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I want to write a bridge adapt between non ZMQ socket and ZMQ socket.

client code:

```
import socket

if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 8888
    BUFFER = 4096

    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print sock
        ret = sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        print ret

        ret = sock.send('hello, tcpServer!')
        print ret
        recv = sock.recv(BUFFER)
        print ('[tcpServer siad]: %s' % recv)
        sock.close()
    except e:
        print e
```

proxy code, use this proxy to send request to ZMQ_REP server.

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__':

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.STREAM)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:8888")

    socket_req = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket_req.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")

    while True:
        clientid, message = socket.recv_multipart();

        print("id: %r" % clientid)
        print("request:",message.decode('utf8'))

        socket_req.send(clientid, flags=zmq.SNDMORE, copy=False)
        socket_req.send("Hi", copy=False)

        clientid, message = socket_req.recv_multipart()


        print("id: %r" % clientid)
        print("request:",message.decode('utf8'))
```

ZMQ_REP server code:

```
import zmq
import time
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':

    port = '5556'
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = sys.argv[1]
        int(port)

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

    while True:
        message = socket.recv()
        print "Received request: ", message
        time.sleep(1)
        socket.send("world from %s" % port)
```

the REQ get error:

```
Received request:  k
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "req_server.py", line 21, in <module>
    socket.send("world from %s" % port)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 574, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5434)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 621, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5196)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 181, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._send_copy (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:2035)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 21, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:6248)
zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First point: It's generally not recommended to use REQ/REP in zmq. Use the more general DEALER/ROUTER combination. The only difference:

1. When the ROUTER recvs, a routing ID is the first part of the message. This is used to route replies back to the sender.
2. the lock-step req/rep/req/rep sequence is not enforced (this is the error you are seeing).

Here's a version of your proxy using DEALER:

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__':

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.STREAM)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:8888")

    socket_req = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    socket_req.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")

    while True:
        clientid, message = socket.recv_multipart()

        print("id: %r" % clientid)
        print("request: %s" % message.decode('utf8'))

        socket_req.send(message)

        reply = socket_req.recv()
        print("reply: %s" % reply.decode('utf8'))

        socket.send_multipart([clientid, reply])
```

And your server, using ROUTER:

```
import zmq
import time
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':

    port = 5556
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%i" % port)

    while True:
        message = socket.recv_multipart()
        req_id = message[0]
        print("Received request: %s" % message[1:])
        time.sleep(1)
        socket.send_multipart([req_id, "world from %s" % port])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
socket_req.send(clientid, flags=zmq.SNDMORE, copy=False)
socket_req.send("Hi", copy=False)
```

Best guess is that it's not properly registering the SNDMORE flag and attempting to send a whole new request rather than appending to the first one (thus breaking the strict SEND/RECEIVE order for REQ sockets)... thus the "current state" of the socket would not allow it to send the second part of your message.  Try using `send_multipart()`, or validating that your parameters are being passed in correctly.

Comment: I just tried send_multipart(), I got the same Error on the REP server.

Comment: using ZMQ's SOCK_STREAM to get a message, we get  a ID in the msg, should I sent the msg to REQ server with the ID ?

Comment: That's what you're pulling off into the `clientid` variable?  I recall some discussion around ROUTER sockets about maintaining that ID in the proxy and then attaching it back to communicate back to the original client (it should be in the zmq guide, chapter 5 or later I think).  So, try that.